# How can I think about Scene Delegate willconnnectTo method?

Tags: ios, swift

I have usual Scenedelegate willConnectTo method as pretty common. My question is when I put a breakpoint to inside of this and close the app slide up ( kill the app ) and reopen it doesn`t come to this breakpoint or print anything

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var coordinator: Coordinator?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>Not printing<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
      
    }

}
```

I am sure I am missing some concept and there is nice explanation by more experienced developers than me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your code, `willConnect`, or anything else. You're not reopening the app from within Xcode (Run), you're just clicking the app icon in the simulator / device. So you're not debugging. So no breakpoints and no printing to the console, because those are Xcode features, and you're not running the app from Xcode.

There *is* a way to hook the Xcode debugger in when you launch by clicking the icon, but you're not doing that.

Comment: What is the hooking way ? How can search it ?

Comment: I talk about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67466823/341994